# Solving the diffusion equation with a constant flux boundary condition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

In a course notes at MIT ([here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/materials-science-and-engineering/3-185-transport-phenomena-in-materials-engineering-fall-2003/study-materials/handout_htrans.pdf)), it is mentioned that
[image]
Could you please explain how this solution is mathematically derived for these boundary conditions?